# list of list in instance of object (java)

Tags: java, list, object

I have defined a class 'student'. Each instance of the class has a name and n*m preferences (which are String).

```
public class Student {
    String firstName;
    List<List<String>> choice = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    public Student(String name1, List<List<String>> preference){
        this.firstName = name1;
        this.choice.addAll(preference); 
    }
}
```

Next, I have a list in which each student object could be saved.

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

Now the problem is, when I save one student in the list it is working fine. However, When I add the second student to the list the preferences of the first students are overwritten. I add and read the data as follow,

```
List<List<String>> preferences = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<String> preferences1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> preferences2 = new ArrayList<String>();


// add first student
preferences.clear(); preferences1.clear(); preferences2.clear();
preferences1.add("Company1"); preferences1.add("Company3");
preferences2.add("Company2"); preferences2.add("Company4");
preferences.add(preferences1); preferences.add(preferences2);
students.add(new Student("Michiel", preferences));

// add second student
preferences.clear(); preferences1.clear(); preferences2.clear();
preferences1.add("Company5"); preferences1.add("Company7");
preferences2.add("Company6"); preferences2.add("Company8");
preferences.add(preferences1); preferences.add(preferences2);
students.add(new Student("William", preferences));

System.out.println(students.get(0).choice);
System.out.println(students.get(1).choice);
```

What is going wrong? I have already tried 'final' in the class.

ps. a small subquestion, do you suggest using Arraylist or List?

Comment: Instead of clearing the `preferences` list, you should create a new one everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reuse the same `List` when you add your next `Student`. What you save is just a reference, so clearing it later will clear all your saved preferences. Create new `List`s of preferences for each `Student`, and you will be fine:

```
...

preferences = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
preferences1 = new ArrayList<String>();
preferences2 = new ArrayList<String>();

// add second student
preferences1.add("Company5"); preferences1.add("Company7");
preferences2.add("Company6"); preferences2.add("Company8");
preferences.add(preferences1); preferences.add(preferences2);
students.add(new Student("William", preferences));
```

> ps. a small subquestion, do you suggest using Arraylist or List?

What you are doing looks just fine. You need to pick some concrete implementation of the `List` interface, and you have chosen `ArrayList` which is perfectly reasonable.
Also, you are declaring your variables of the interface type `List`, which is the preferred way to do it.

Comment: If I do it in this way, are the lines with clear() then still necessary?

Comment: Furthermore, when I add a new list for each student then the list need another name than the previous one.

Edit: This is not true, I defined it as 
    List<List<String>> preferences = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
instead of
    preferences = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Michiel: No, the name is irrelevant, it is just a reference. There is no problem with using the same reference as long as you point it to a new `List` each time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new List of preferences for each student like this :

```
    List<List<String>> preferences1 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    List<String> preferences1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> preferences2 = new ArrayList<String>();


    // add first student
    preferences.clear(); preferences1.clear(); preferences2.clear();
    preferences1.add("Company1"); preferences1.add("Company3");
    preferences2.add("Company2"); preferences2.add("Company4");
    preferences.add(preferences1); preferences.add(preferences2);
    students.add(new Student("Michiel", preferences));

    // add second student

 List<List<String>> secondPreferences = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    List<String> secondPreferences2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> secondPreferences3 = new ArrayList<String>();

// preferences1.clear(); preferences2.clear(); preferences3.clear(); // you don't need to clear those ! as they are new lists

    secondPreferences2.add("Company5"); secondPreferences2.add("Company7");
    secondPreferences3.add("Company6"); secondPreferences3.add("Company8");
    secondPreferences.add(preferences1); secondPreferences.add(preferences2);
    students.add(new Student("William", secondPreferences));

    System.out.println(students.get(0).choice);
    System.out.println(students.get(1).choice);
```

Good luck.

Comment: In this answer for each student a new name is needed. Therefore I prefer the first answer since I do not know the number of students.

Comment: What has the name of the student to do with the lists references ?

Comment: I mean the name of the references, in your example secondPreferences2.